# Google now in response to android wear action

Tags: android, wear-os

Can i execute a google now voice search on my watch in response to the voice action to my wear notification (using remoteInput)?

The action takes in a pendingintent which spawns an activity on my handheld device, but i want to execute a google now voice search on my wrist watch, without starting new activity on the handheld device. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the actions (PendingIntents) that you add to a notification on your phone are targeted for the phone so when you open the notification on the watch and press on that, the PendingIntent will be invoked on your phone; there is no action performed on your watch so what you'd like to do is not possible via notifications that are bridged from your phone to your watch. If you want to do a bit more work, then you can send a message to your watch and have a watch app that can interpret that and create a notification there directly on your watch. Then the actions set on that notifications are local to the watch.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, is there a way to parse the current notification card's content on which the voice action was done? In my case, when i say "weather" it should show up the current weather for the place that is my current notification card's content.